# Dereference vector pointer to access element

Tags: c++, vector, dereference

If i have in C++ a pointer to a vector:

```
vector<int>* vecPtr;
```

And i'd like to access an element of the vector, then i can do this by dereferncing the vector:

```
int a = (*vecPtr)[i];
```

but will this dereferencing actually create a copy of my vector on the stack? let's say the vector stores 10000 ints, will by dereferencing the vecPtr 10000 ints be copied?

Thanks!

Comment: A pointer to a vector is a fairly uncommon thing - consider if you should really have a reference or a vector value.

Comment: It's not uncommon at all, a reference to a vector is exactly the same as a pointer to a vector as far as the generated machine code is concerned. Anyone who thinks there's any meaningful difference between pointers and references is fooling themselves.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

10000 `int`s will not be copied. Dereferencing is very cheap.

To make it clear you can rewrite

```
int a = (*vecPtr)[i];
```

as

```
vector<int>& vecRef = *vecPtr; // vector is not copied here
int a = vecRef[i];
```

In addition, if you are afraid that the whole data stored in `vector` will be located on the stack and you use `vector<int>*` instead of `vector<int>` to avoid this: this is not the case.
Actually only a fixed amount of memory is used on the stack (about 16-20 bytes depending on the implementation), independently of the number of elements stored in the `vector`.
The `vector` itself allocates memory and stores elements on the heap.

Comment: Wow, I never knew that it was legal to have references as data types (vector<int>& vecRef). I always thought this was restricted to function parameters. This is good info to have!

Comment: if you don't put the parentheses around the (\*vecPtr) you will get compiler error: error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand type is ‘...... template related long text not shown

Comment: Good to know. On the other hand `vector<int> copied = *vecPtr;` does seem to copy the entire vector.

Answer (score 56):

No, nothing will be copied; dereferencing just tells C++ that you want to invoke operator[] on the *vector*, not on your *pointer*, `vecPtr`.  If you didn't dereference, C++ would try to look for an operator[] defined on the `std::vector<int>*` type.

This can get really confusing, since `operator[]` is defined for all pointer types, but it amounts to offsetting the pointer as though it pointed to an array of `vector<int>`.  If you'd really only allocated a single vector there, then for any index other than `0`, the expression evaluates to a reference to garbage, so you'll get either a segfault or something you did not expect.

In general, accessing vectors through a pointer is a pain, and the `(*vecPtr)[index]` syntax is awkward (but better than `vecPtr->operator[](index)`).  Instead, you can use:

```
vecPtr->at(index)
```

This actually checks ranges, unlike `operator[]`, so if you don't want to pay the price for checking if index is in bounds, you're stuck with `(*vecPtr)[]`.

Comment: Minor clarification. operator[] is defined for the std::vector<int>*, because operator[] is defined for any pointer. But it returns no int as expected but reference to the std::vector<int> with trash inside and which can not be assigned to int.

Comment: Please does this apply when want to pass the vector to function that expects `const std::vector<int>&` as a parameter?

Comment: is `at` as fast as accessing element by the index?